# Connect Cloudformation configurated beanstalk setup to an existing AWS site-to-site VPN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have this current Cloudformation config setup:

PasteBin example [here](https://pastebin.com/uCcWPv3t)

This runs a web app, there's also some networking config in there which routes outbound traffic through a nat gateway with an elastic ip.

--
Separately we have a manually created site-to-site VPN setup in AWS

screenshot, elastic ip created by cloudformation :
[image: screenshot, elastic ip created by cloudformation]

The other side of the VPN specified that our private ip range for the connection to work has to be in `192.168.242.0/24`.

Also they have specifically whitelisted `192.168.242.230` at their end. Which is the private ip of the elasticip which the Cloudformation above created.

How can I establish a connection from my EBS ec2 instance to a server protected by this VPN? At the moment the connection just times out.

Comment: Route table like @sudharsan siad, security groups open between the two subnets as well. Is the VPN tunnel up as well? Did you use a software vpn or AWS managed VPN? The aws managed tunnel will only come up when traffic on your side of it goes over it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add a route table rule to allow traffic to X.X.X.X/X flow via the Virtual Private Gateway(vgw-xxxxxx)

```
Destination  Target
x.x.x.x/x    vgw-xxxxxx
```